# How to print an index of an integer array for the index number times. For example: if the index = 3 then print 3 for three time

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to write a code that takes the size of the array and the elements of the array from the user,

input:

```
3
5
8
3
```

and then print,

output:

```
5 5 5 5 5
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
3 3 3
```

this is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int T;
    cin >> T;
    int arr [ 10000 ];
    int i;
    for ( i=0; i<T; ++i) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    for ( i=0; i<T; ++i) {
        for ( int j=0; j<i ; ++j ) {
            cout<< arr[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `j < i` looks incorrect.  You want to print the number of times equal to the value at that index, not the index itself. Should be `j < arr[i]`.

Comment: The question describes the array elements being input from the user, but there is no evidence of this.  It's unclear why you need an array at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will help you if I have understood your question correctly.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    std::cout << "Please enter array size: ";
    std::cin >> size;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << size << " ";
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Please enter array size: 8
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8

Please enter array size: 3
3 3 3
```

**Note:**  `using namespace std;` is not a good habit.